# Detecting mistakes in words and fix them when classifying text (NLP)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, nlp

Hi there✌I make a neural network that classifies the text. First I need to prepare the text and I ran into the problem of "mistakes in words". How can they be found and corrected? And what ideas do you have? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can correct spelling errors by maintaining a vocabulary and finding the closest valid word using a string metric like the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). There are also some more advanced Python tools, like [SpaCy Hunspell](https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy_hunspell). That being said, if you plan to use pre-trained word embeddings I wouldn't worry too much about text normalisation, as the embeddings will likely contain most common spelling variants. You can check how many out-of-vocabulary words you have in your data to see if it's worth investing time in extra cleaning except for basic tokenisation (and converting everything to lowercase).

Comment: Thx very much. Could you help me with one more question? The result of my model is 0.83. Is there a chance that if I find and fix mistakes in text the result rises to 0.9..?

Comment: What is the model you're using? How do you encode text?